# How do I remove margin above error text in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

Could anyone help me? I am struggling to remove margin in TextFormField.

[image: Click here to see the screenshot]

Below is the code.

```
class TextFieldItemTemp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        errorText: 'This field is required',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 3.0),
        ),
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 3.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your related code?

Comment: @Akif Already shared sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0.7),` to *InputDecoration*.

Comment: @Chanin With upvoting you make me happy :)

Comment: I very wanted to do that but I couldnot. Need more reputation to  upvote. :( sorry @BeHappy

Comment: Nice! That works for the vertical spacing. What about horizontal? My input has an inner padding (left) and the error message takes the same left padding. How can I prevent that from happening only to the error message?

Comment: If you have multiple lines of error message, this solution will not work

Answer (score 1):

Inside input decorator use this property

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero
```